# Access cross-domain iframe elements using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, iframe

I have an iframe in my html page and I want to access some content from the page opened in this iframe.

```
<table border="1" width="100%" height="100%">
    <tr>
        <td id = "freebase_td">
        <iframe id = "freebase_frame" src="http://www.freebase.com/view/en/angelina_jolie" width="100%" height="400px"></iframe>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

In this web page's source,

```
  <h1 id="page-title">
    Angelina Jolie
  </h1>
```

I want to access the content in the h1 tag with id "page-title" using javascript. Could it be possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe

Comment: Are the pages on two separate domains? So, the page above and [http://www.freebase.com/view/en/angelina_jolie](http://www.freebase.com/view/en/angelina_jolie)?

Comment: You can't. Google "same origin policy" to see why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should first read about the [browser's same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript).  This prevents javascript from a frame or window or iframe in one origin from accessing the content or scripts in another frame in a different origin.  So, if your iframe is not the same origin as the page of your script, then it cannot directly access the iframe's contents.

If you have one of the latest browsers and you code both frames to cooperate (which means you have to control the javascript code in both frames), there is a new feature called [window messaging](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.postMessage) that can be used to pass information between frames from different origins.

Comment: what is the solution you got saxena?