# Parsing html table from different domain

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, cross-domain

i'm making an iOS app for showing schedule for my college. 
I'm kinda new in javascript, i thought it's simple until now. I know this task may be simple and trivial, but listen:
My application generates link with parameters and then creates a dynamic page with an iframe and opens link within it (src of an iframe sets to generated link), link leads to a page on a different domain, it has a HTML table with needed data in it's cells, each cell has it's own attribute, so i thought i could simply find each needed cell by it using DOM, but accessing iframe's DOM doesn't work. I can change absolutely nothing on server side - even college technicians do not know how it works and of course they'll not touch anything until it breakes. 
So the question is: how can i get the text from the cells of that table by knowing their attributes and store it as a variable in javascript?

Almost forgot, example of a page itself:
http://ikis.tsogu.ru/shedule/show_shedule.php?action=group&union=0&sid=96&gr=111&year=2015&vr=0

Comment: Please edit your question instead of adding more info in the comments.

Comment: i can't use PHP b/c it'll be an iphone app...
w8
i think i can host a server running PHP, and then send this link to it and, then server will do it's work with the page and send the data back, right?
Where can i read more about this?

Comment: "but accessing iframe's DOM doesn't work" — No, it doesn't. Deal with this outside of the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you cant. Due to same-origin policy. Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7804240/access-cross-domain-iframe-elements-using-javascript) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6170925/get-dom-content-of-cross-domain-iframe) similar questions.